# Case-insensitive and escaping chars Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Can anyone help me do a **case insensitive** query and **escaping single and double quotes** in Neo4j?

Ex: mary's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function toLower() and use the escape char "\".  For example:

```
MATCH (n:Person) 
WHERE toLower(n.name) = "mary\'s" 
RETURN n

Result:
╒═════════════════╕
│"person"         │
╞═════════════════╡
│{"name":"Mary's"}│
└─────────────────┘
```